# Convert Objective-C code to Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, core-bluetooth, nrf51, dfu

I have been working with nrf51x. I have a sample code written in Obj-C. I was not able to convert it to Swift.

```
uint8_t value = ACTIVATE_AND_RESET_REQUEST;
[self.bluetoothPeripheral writeValue:[NSData dataWithBytes:&value length:sizeof(value)] forCharacteristic:self.dfuControlPointCharacteristic type:CBCharacteristicWriteWithResponse];
```

I tried

```
var value: UInt8 = DfuOperations.VALIDATE_FIRMWARE_REQUEST.rawValue
let ptr = UnsafePointer<Void>(value)
let data = NSData(ptr, length: sizeofValue(value))
dfuPeripheral!.writeValue(data, forCharacteristic: self.dfuControlPointCharacteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.WithResponse)
```

and this one

```
var value: UInt8 = DfuOperations.VALIDATE_FIRMWARE_REQUEST.rawValue
let data = NSData(&value, length: sizeofValue(value))
```

Can any one help me?
Thank you very much

Comment: Check out the link provided in this  [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33564737/5222077)

Comment: @kye the conversion provided by this tool doesn't work.

Comment: I dont think its updated to swift 2.1 yet

Comment: I'm not working with swift 2.1

Comment: What exactly is not working in your code? What is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Robert answer I was able to find a solution. 
I finally created a method that writes an array of [UInt8] to a CBCharacteristic.
Here is the code:

```
func updateValueForCharacteristic(characteristic: CBCharacteristic, value: [UInt8], writeType: CBCharacteristicWriteType = CBCharacteristicWriteType.WithResponse){
    let data = NSData(bytes: value, length: sizeofValue(value))
    dfuPeripheral!.writeValue(data, forCharacteristic: characteristic, type: writeType)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The class below builds without error. I am using Xcode 7.1.

```
import Foundation
import CoreBluetooth

class Test {
    func test(bluetoothPeripheral: CBPeripheral, dfuControlPointCharacteristic: CBCharacteristic) {
        let value = UInt8(ACTIVATE_AND_RESET_REQUEST.rawValue)
        let encodedValue = NSData(bytes: [value], length: sizeof(UInt8))
        bluetoothPeripheral.writeValue(encodedValue, forCharacteristic: dfuControlPointCharacteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.WithResponse)
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you are using `UInt32` when the original code is using `UInt8`?

Comment: Thanks @RobertVaessen